# How to debug really early in the startup process

Tags: boot

Lately my computer has not been starting up properly about 50% of the time. When it fails I see a completely blank screen, it doesn't even display the bios splash page or the GRUB bootloader. I do not think this is simply a case of the video card being an issue as I cannot ping the computer over the lan.

Is there any way to debug what might be going wrong so early in the boot process?

Comment: What OS is it?.

Comment: Does the machine power on but not post or does the power also not appear to come on?

Comment: The machine powers on and remains powered on, I can hear it running even though it doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: Which OS? Please use the EDIT button to add this and any other relevant information to the body of the question itself.